# How can I open a specific telegram account with preloaded text message

Tags: telegram

Is it possible to open a specific account with a preloaded text like this:

```
tg://resolve?domain={USER_NAME}&text=Hi, default message
https://t.me/{USER_NAME}?text=Hi, default message
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't (yet) a option to open a chat for a specific user, however, you can open the Telegram app, with an preloaded text, the user get's the option to pick a recipient from there chat list;

Use the following url;

```
tg://msg_url?url=Hi%21%20I%27m%20an%20example%21
```

Where;

- `url` is the preloaded message (or link) (url-encoded)

---

After pressing the link, Telegram will ask for a recipent ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLXrM.png)).

If the user selects a chat from the sidebar, the preloaded text will be filled in the chat box ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEOKX.png))

Comment: Too bad that is missing.

Comment: @HAßdøµ, yea there are quite some people looking for something like this, I hope they add it soon! I'll update my answer if I'll find some new info!