# Similar message sending via url with Telegram

Tags: url, telegram, message

Similar to WhatsApp example `https://wa.me/6588888888?text=I%27m%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale`, how to achieve it with Telegram with URL only? The username and message are required.

I will put the URL in HTML anchor tag `href` attribute e.g. `<a href="https://wa.me/6588888888?text=I%27m%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale" target="_blank">Click</a>`. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I open a specific telegram account with preloaded text message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811464/how-can-i-open-a-specific-telegram-account-with-preloaded-text-message)

Comment: I need both user and text together.. The suggested not working, it's either username or text.